# Put two lines of content on the same line and add a comma in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've exported a list of users from a website. The list looks like this:

```
name1
name1@email.com
name2
name2@email.com
name3
name3@email.com
```

How can I make it look like this using Notepad++? I figure it will need regex & CTRL + H.

```
name1,name1@email.com
name2,name2@email.com
name3,name3@email.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Find what: ^([^@\r\n]+)\r\n([^\r\n]+)$
Replace with: $1,$2
```

Comment: How can I use that and search for all types of emails? Some in my list are using mail.com, hotmail.com and some gmail.com. Thanks.

Comment: what is the rule? one line with no `@`, and one line with `@`?

Comment: The first line got no @ and the second one got @, yes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

find: `\r?\n(.*\r?\n?)`
replace: `,$1`

The idea is to replace the newline with a comma half the time.

Answer (score 0):

I know you have accepted a good answer, but for the record, since Notepad++ uses PCRE, bear in mind that we can use all kinds of features such as `\R` and subroutines:

Search: `(?m)^(?+2)\R++(([\w[:punct:]]+)@(?-1))`

Replace: `\1,\2`

This is clearly over the top, but it's good to know that `\R` can replace `\r\n`.